# Can you set autorization attributes at a table level in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5

I know you can set the authorize attribute at and the controller level and at the action leve, but lets say I have a table in a view and I want some users to be able to only see certain columns and some users can edit certain columns. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would put an array called `VisibleColums` inside my `Model`, at least I would prepare such logic inside the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You'd filter the grid based on the user/role (in the controller action that builds the grid). Same for edit feature. Hide/display the edit button for certain users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box declarative security solution I know about for such granular level like a view parts. You should build the views on your own and allow to render some of its parts based on the set of roles some users have and some users don't. You can also create separate partial views depends on how much they are going to differ based on the authorization levels in your system.